# Jquery.animate() on webkit background

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

How do I use the Jquery method .animate() on $(this) for the following:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2d2d2d), to(#373737))
```

I tried using:

```
$(this).css("background", "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#d70000), to(#679938))");
```

Which works fine, but I want to define the time it takes for the transition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@-webkit-keyframes changeBG {
    0% {
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2d2d2d), to(#373737));
}
50% {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#666), to(#737373));
}
100% {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#2d2d2d), to(#373737));
}
```

I solved the problem using -webkit-keyframes and a change in class for a duration of 200ms. If anyone has an idea, how to involve the -webkit-keyframes directly with Jquery, without shifting classes, please write your answer. Also, I have got no clue, as to why .animate() dindn't work. I'd be thankful, if anyone has the answer to that

```
$(this).addClass('akt');
        setTimeout(function () { $(this).removeClass('akt'); }, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery *animate method like so:*

```
$(this).animate({"background": "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left   bottom, from(#d70000), to(#679938))"}, 4000/* Your transition MS here, ex. 4000 */);
```

For more information about the *animate* method, click [***here.***](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

If you're using a lower version of jQuery (well, this method was released since version 1.0.0, but some versions might not support it), and the animate method doesn't work, then this is an alternative :

```
$(this).delay(4000).css("background", "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#d70000), to(#679938))");
```

Comment: I can't get it to work using the above code. I'm using Jquery 1.8.4, anything to do with that?

Comment: Try using : `$(this).delay(4000).css("background", "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#d70000), to(#679938))");`

Comment: no luck, also tried: ' $(this).addClass("akt");
    setTimeout(function () { $(this).removeClass("ak"'); }, 3000); '

Comment: Seems like i'm running some sort of problem with the element. It's an input, type="button"

Comment: Try using the button tag instead, and see how it goes.